# Performance profiling for Openresty and Lua

Tags: lua, openresty

I'm using **Openresty version 1.15.8.1** and **Lua version 5.2.4** as proxy pass server.

I have many functions and codes here and its so slow and CPU expensive now to process and validate my requests. I want to find out what peace of code is making my app so slow. There are many profiling scripts out there but most of them are not working well!  How can I really profile my codes find out CPU and RAM and time usage of each functions? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I have been working with Openresty for many years, but don't understand this part of your question - "Lua version 5.2.4 as proxy pass server". Can you elaborate?

Comment: `os.clock()` is your friend

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer it just give me seconds time not milliseconds. its not useful for that. anyway to get milisec?

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler  some of my requests need to be validate and auth by lua code. So it comes to /location block, I send it to Lua validator file, it validate the request, then pass it or reject it.  This validation Lua file makes my Nginx a little a bit slower.

Comment: How do you run your lua file? OpenResty has Lua hooks for many request processing phases. It uses very optimized LuaJIT, not stock and slow Lua 5.2. If you run your Lua validator file by os.execute() or similar - you would have poor performance of course. You need to rewrite this Lua file using Nginx async Lua flavor

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler  ```location ~ /my_request {
    rewrite_by_lua_file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/html/default/validator.lua;
}```

Comment: @SamiAlMorshedi `os.clock()` gives milliseconds, that's the whole point of the function.

Comment: @SamiAlMorshedi it is correct way to run Lua why do you think it uses Lua 5.2? It should be LuaJIT

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler aha gotcha. So do you have any solution for me? profiling?

Comment: @SamiAlMorshedi It depends from which API/libraries do you use. There are some best practices. You must not use any blocking operations. like sync HTTP requests, start external processes, etc.

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler  I use redis, cjson libraries. My lua file is almost 550 lines code if its important. many conditions and validations of request body and headers.

Comment: @SamiAlMorshedi hope you use lua-resty-redis libray. you may use https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxnow for profiling

Comment: @SamiAlMorshedi also https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxupdate_time first to get accurate time

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler tna so much

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Microsecond Resolution timer --

local ffi = require("ffi")

ffi.cdef[[
      typedef long time_t;

      typedef struct timeval {
         time_t tv_sec;
         time_t tv_usec;
      } timeval;

      int gettimeofday(struct timeval* t, void* tzp);
]]

local gettimeofday_struct = ffi.new("timeval")

local gettimeofday = function()
   ffi.C.gettimeofday(gettimeofday_struct, nil)
   return tonumber(gettimeofday_struct.tv_sec) * 1000000 + 
      tonumber(gettimeofday_struct.tv_usec)
end
```